# URL in iPhone SMS content

Tags: iphone

I'm developing an iPhone application where SMS native application should open when the user clicks the button.

This is working fine and I am also able to copy the content to clipboard when the user clicks on the button.

But I want to provide a URL in the SMS content which I am copying so that the user click on the URL to open it in the browser.

Can anyone suggest me how to provide clickable URL in SMS content?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can simply encode the URL in the SMS content - the iPhone SMS application will display it as a clickable/tappable URL.
This is, of course, assuming that you simply want to send a clickable link. As rpetrich mentions, there is no way to send rich content directly via SMS.

Comment: encoding the url in the content u mean, i should put just www.google.com or something similar to html anchor tag.

Comment: Putting http://www.google.com (Or most any full URI with protocol specifier, proto://uri; SO seems to convert the URL into a link and strip the http://.) should work properly, yes.

Answer (score 0):

The APIs for copying rich text (HTML) content to the clipboard are private for the time being.  Even if they weren't, SMS messages do not support them--I think MMS messages do, but on some carriers they're more expensive.